# Haskell -- get TypeRep from concrete type instance

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, dynamic-typing

I want to write a function with this type signature:

```
getTypeRep :: Typeable a => t a -> TypeRep
```

where the TypeRep will be the type representation for *a*, not for *t a*. That is, the compiler should automatically return the correct type representation at any call sites [to *getTypeRep*], which will have concrete types for *a*.

To add some context, I want to create a "Dynamic type" data type, with the twist that it will remember the top-level type, but not its parameter. For example, I want to turn *MyClass a* into *Dynamic MyClass*, and the above function will be used to create instances of *Dynamic MyClass* that store a representation of the type parameter *a*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, how about using scoped type variables to select the inner component:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Dynamic
import Data.Typeable

getTypeRep :: forall t a . Typeable a => t a -> TypeRep
getTypeRep _ = typeOf (undefined :: a)
```

Works for me:

```
*Main> getTypeRep (Just ())
()
*Main> getTypeRep (Just 7)
Integer
*Main> getTypeRep ([True])
Bool
```

Interesting design.

Answer (score 8):

On a tangential note to Don's solution, notice that code rarely *require* ScopedTypeVariables.  It just makes the solution cleaner (but less portable).  The solution without scoped types is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
import Data.Typeable

helper :: t a -> a
helper _ = undefined

getTypeRep :: forall t a. Typeable a => t a -> TypeRep
getTypeRep = typeOf . helper
```

Answer (score 0):

This function (now) exists in `Data.Typeable` [typeRep](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeRep)